# Simplexml_load_file issues caused by proxy

Tags: php, xml, curl, simplexml

I've built a script locally which works fine. I've now moved that script onto a server that's behind a proxy and I've come into some issues.

Here's the code:

```
    $yahooXML = simplexml_load_file('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22'.$from.''.$to.'%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys'); 

    print_r($yahooXML);
    die();
```

I'm getting a failed to open stream and I/O warning : failed to load external entity error using this.

I explored using cURL to load the data and then parse with simplexml but not sure if this is possible?

any ideas?

Edit:

I loaded the page with CURL which failed as well so I added the proxy option in and it fixed it. Now I just need to load this with XML?

```
   function curl($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxysg.uwe.ac.uk:8080'); 
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }


    $feed = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22'.$from.''.$to.'%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';
    $data = curl($feed);

    echo $data;
    die();
```

Comment: Try fetching the xml separately, and examine it. sounds more like there's a character entity in there that's defined externally, and that external definition can be loaded.

Comment: How would I do that? I just tried using file_get_contents to grab the page but I'm getting an  failed to open stream error. (entity error is gone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the XML file and you've verified that it's proper XML, you can load it into php via [simplexml_load_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or [simplexml_load_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) depending on what you have.

If your $data var is a string w/well formed XML, then:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($xml);
```

should work just fine.  Of course, now you have a simple xml object, which will work with any of the normal simplexml functions.